# HTTPS and HTTP issue on server with SSL

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, http, ssl-certificate, https

I have a site [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) for which i purchased **SSL** cert and installed.

And it was working fine, I also have a subdomain with app.example.com which was not on SSL.

Both [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and app.example.com are on same IP address.

At later we decided to put SSL only on app.example.com and then i configured SSL with app.example.com and it worked fine,

Now the issue is that **Google** is indexing my site as https://www.example.com/ and when users hits the web , Invalid security warning is issued and when user allow security issue they are shown my app.example.com contents.

Note: I have my SSL configuration files in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

The contents of the ssl.conf are below.

NOTE: I tried solutions in .httaccess but none of those worked. Like redirecting 301 redirects etc

http://pastebin.com/GCWhpQJq

Comment: It's not your ssl.conf, but more likely your httpd.conf, where you have some sort of misconfiguration.

Comment: The user can't be redirected until after they've connected to the site.  They won't connect to the site because the SSL certificate on the server is no longer for www.example.com.  You'll have to wait for google to reindex the site without https, or maybe the Webmaster Tools can help you remove the https url (but may not get the http url in its place)

Answer (score 2):

Since the two domains are under the same IP address you will need a SAN (multi domain) certificate.  Issue the cert for www.example.com and then add www.app.example.com in the SAN field and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your server to permanently redirect SSL (HTTPS) requests for www.frostbox.com to HTTP.  Google should update its index on the next pass.  This will also redirect users if they accept the certificate.

Make sure your configuration at Google is for http://www.frostbox.com.  On the Google site you can request a rescan of your site which should help resolve the issue faster.

On the certificate side, you could get your certificate reissued with www.frostbox.com as an alias.  This would resolve the mismatched certificate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by giving each site its own IP address. That is, www.example.com would have one IP address, and app.frostbox.com would have another.

Comment: Please can you help me, how can i give different IP address for it?